# Add or Delete jQuery sortable element and remember order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm implementing something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GUpQw/7/) in one of my Wordpress metabox. User should be able to add and remove jquery-ui sortable elements and remember the position(order) of the elements exists.

I already know how to remember the position(order) when the elements are resorted by dragging and dropping.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('ul').sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var data = jQuery(this).sortable('toArray');
            jQuery('#elements-order').val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This will output an array which contains the order like `1,2,3,5,4` But, when new elements are added or elements are deleted,  how to make this code run to remember the order of the new elements.

This is the code I use to Add elements

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {;
        var wrapperSize = jQuery("#element-area-top").width();
        (function () {
            jQuery(".add-element").on("click", ".add-item", function () {

                var start = jQuery("#sortable"),
                selectBoxVal = jQuery("#element-list").val();

                var element = null;

                element = ('<li></li>');      
                var newRow = jQuery(element);
                jQuery(start).append(newRow);

                jQuery("#elements-order").val(jQuery('#elements-order').val() + i+',');

        });
})();
```

This is the code I use to delete elements

```
jQuery("#sortable").on("click", ".delete", function () {
    jQuery(this).parents(/*someelement*/).remove();
});
```

So, could anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle demo of ur problem? :)

Comment: No, actually, my problem is not under JS scope. It's about saving the order newly added elements. What I have already made has the exact functionality as the Fiddle I've shown you. But, how to save the position in the Wordpress DB ?

Comment: Ajax on order change...javascript array POST...serialize to string...save to DB...?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want... But how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get sort order with same logic in add/delete functions as well (just replace this with '#ul').

```
var data = jQuery('#ul').sortable('toArray');
jQuery("#elements-order").val(data);
```

Or even better, put above code in a common function and just call common function. Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbzwhqss/2/) demonstrating same.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I wanted. :) Thanks a million. I was struggling how to use that loadSortOrder() under my delete function. Thanks again!